# Android Studio SQLite Cursor Looping

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
for (int i=0; i-1<nAlt-1; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j-1<nKri-1; j++) {
        Cursor cekData = aturanDB.checkData(String.valueOf(nn.get(i)), String.valueOf(ci.get(j)));
       try {
           while (cekData.moveToNext()){
               altkri.add(cekData.getString(cekData.getColumnIndex(AturanDB.row_nilai)));
               nilaialtrkri = altkri.toArray(new String[i][j]);
               Toast.makeText(Diagnosa.this, String.valueOf(altkri.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            } finally {
                            cekData.close();
                      }
                    }
                }
```

can you help me for something wrong ?. Nothing process when executing

Comment: Please try for a [mre], according to [ask].